# insertRow() in QT5.4

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5.4

Is there a limit in the number of rows that can be inserted using `insertRow()` of `QTableWidget Class`?

In my program, I increment a variable, say count, and use the statement `insertRow(count)`. It works perfectly if `count <= 500`. If `count > 500`, the code stops running. I am working in `MSVS2013`.

EDIT : Code added

```
    QXmlStreamReader xs(ba);
    int i=-2;
    QTableWidgetItem* titem=NULL;

    QStringList qslHeaders;
    map < QString, pair<QString, QString >> HeaderMap;
    int map_index = 0;
    int col_count_set = 0;
    map<QString, pair<QString, QString>>::iterator iter;
    while (!xs.atEnd())
    {
        bool flag = true;
        ++i;
        if (xs.readNextStartElement() && xs.name().toString() == "ROW")
        {
            insertRow(i);
            while (flag)
            {
                switch (xs.readNext())
                {
                case QXmlStreamReader::StartElement:
                {
                    QString name = xs.name().toString();

                    //Insert data to map here
                }
                break;

                case QXmlStreamReader::EndElement:
                    if (xs.name().toString() == "ROW")
                    {
                        map_index = 0;
                        if (HeaderMap.size()>0 && col_count_set == 0)
                        {
                            setColumnCount(HeaderMap.size());
                            col_count_set++;
                        }
                        iter = HeaderMap.begin();
                        while (iter != HeaderMap.end())
                        {
                            titem = new QTableWidgetItem(iter->second.first);
                            setItem(i, map_index, titem);
                            iter++;
                            map_index++;
                        }
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // WRITTEN FOR DEBUGGING
        if (i > 501)
            break;
       // DEBUG
    }
    iter = HeaderMap.begin();
    while (iter != HeaderMap.end())
    {
        if (!qslHeaders.contains(iter->second.second))
        {
            qslHeaders.append(iter->second.second);
        }
        iter++;
    }
    setHorizontalHeaderLabels(qslHeaders);
```

Comment: Theoretically it is only limited by the integer size, but `QTableWidget` will perform slowly on the large number of items. Use `QTableView` instead. What means "code stops running"?

Comment: I tried developing an application which hangs when the row size is greater than `500`. I tried debugging the code, and when `501` is reached , I cannot debug the code further. I have to stop the application and start again.

Comment: Bug on your side. I have seen QTableWidgets with more than 500 rows.

Comment: Just show us some code, e.g. how do you create your QTableWidget? Stack? Heap?

Comment: @Greenflow : added the portion of code

Comment: What do you think I can see in this peep hole over your code? I was sure, that somewhere in your code you have an 'insertRow'. This is the most uninteresting part. More interesting is how you create your QTableWidget... on the heap? Or on the stack? Might be a memory problem. Though 500 rows is very low for that. Unless you do something wasteful somewhere else.

Comment: Just to let you know.. I just created a QTableWidget with 1000000 insertRows... took only 7 minutes and 53 seconds on my machine. But worked.

Comment: You might want to try QStandardItemModel with QTreeView, if you're not familiar yet with implementing your own models. (That would be the most scalable solution though)